# How Get data variables from Data file (nested json) in the body request from Postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have JSON file for collection runner

```
[{
      "Profile": {
        "Name" : "Andrew"
        }
}]
```

How can I get name value 'Name' and put to body request
I tried `{{Profile.Name}}`, `{{data.Profile.Name}}` but it did not work.
If i tried `{{Profile}}` - then i have `[Object Object]` in the body.

Comment: You have it in an array so you have to access it as such

Comment: {{data[0].Profile.Name}}